# startUpdatingLocation is working only when wifi is ON but not when only 3G in ON

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i have tried to get the longitude/latitude of the user current location, my code is simply this :

**MyLocationManager.h**

```
@interface MyLocationManager : NSObject

+(MyLocationManager*)sharedInstance;
-(void)checkAndStartLocationManager;
-(void)stopUpdatingLocation;
@end
```

**MyLocationManager.m**

```
+ (MyLocationManager*)sharedInstance
{
    static id  _sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
    _sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    MyLocationManager *instance = _sharedInstance;
    instance.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    instance.locationManager.delegate = instance;
    instance.locationManager.distanceFilter = 100;
    instance.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    instance.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = YES;
    instance.locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeOtherNavigation;
});
return _sharedInstance;
}

-(void)checkAndStartLocationManager
{
switch([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus])
{
    case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse:
        [self startUpdatingLocation];
        break;

    case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:
                 @selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
            {
                [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
            }
        }
        break;

    case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
        break;

    case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
        break;

    case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways:
        [self startUpdatingLocation];
        break;

        default:
        break;
}
}

-(void)startUpdatingLocation
{
  [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
switch([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus])
{
    case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse:
        [self startUpdatingLocation];
        break;

    case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
        break;

    case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
        break;

    case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
        break;

    case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways:
        [self startUpdatingLocation];
        break;

        default:
        break;
}
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:    (NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    NSString*locationInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"lat - %f, lon -  %f", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude];
    NSLog(@"Location is %@", locationInfo);
   [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError: (NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
}
```

I am using ios 8 and tested on iphone 5 device. Whenever i call,

```
[[MyLocationManager sharedInstance] checkAndStartLocationManager];
```

If wifi on phone is ON then only

```
didUpdateLocations
```

is getting called.
If **wifi is OFF** and only **3G in ON** then i **always received error** as,

**Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"**

Please help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device uses WiFi to fast determine location by crowdsourcing hotspots despite of result may be inaccurate. When you disable WiFi, the only remaining possibility is use GPS module. However, if you are in some building or GPS signal is not strength enough, it will take more time to determine your location and you will get that messages for a while

Comment: Thanks Azat. You were right, it takes more time when either in some building or GPS signal is weak.